# Applying alternate class names for alternate table rows in xsl:foreach loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML is like this

```
 <filters>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Type" FILTERNAME="Malet" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Mængde" FILTERNAME="500" UNITCODE="g" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Anvendelse" FILTERNAME="Kaffemaskine" UNITCODE="" />
</filters>
```

I am looping through each of this filters and printing on separate table rows, My code is like this .

```
                 <xsl:variable name="grouped-filt">
                  <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($filt)/filters">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ISP_WebItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)[1])]" />
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="ISP_WebItem">
    <tr>
        <td width="200px">
            <xsl:value-of select="@FILTER" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)">
                <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="@FILTERNAME" />
                <xsl:if test="@UNITCODE != ''">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@UNITCODE"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Now what I need is to get alternative classes for each tr printed.
example

```
<tr class="odd">data</tr>
<tr class="even">data</tr>
<tr class="odd">data</tr>
<tr class="even">data</tr>
```

Can any one show me a path?

Note:1-above code is made for different purposes like grouping all filters.
      2-I can't use JavaScript for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the position function directly in the template in a similar way to how you're using it in the `for-each`:

```
<xsl:template match="ISP_WebItem">
    <tr>
       <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="(position() mod 2) = 0">even</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>odd</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:attribute>
```

The `position()` is based on the list of nodes seleted by the calling `apply-templates`, i.e. given

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ISP_WebItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)[1])]" />
```

the first `ISP_WebItem` in document order that this selects will have `position() = 1`, the second `position() = 2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible using some javascript like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".pdfgrid tr:even").addClass('even');
$(".pdfgrid tr:odd").addClass('odd');
});
```

Comment: Then anyone know how can we achieve this by using xslt?

Comment: I also would prefer jquery ;-). But remove the "only".

Comment: @Arun I can't understand from where this pdfgrid  came?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<xsl:when test="position() mod 2">


</xsl:when>
```